# Show there are infintely many $n$ s.t. $6n-1$ and $6n+1$ are composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have question to show that there are infinitely many $n$. such that $6n-1$ and $6n+1$ are composite

Assume contradiction

So, there are finite such $n$ such that  $6n-1$, $6n+1$ are composite. Let n be least among then. Then I write $m=n-1$ and for m we get two numbers, $6n-5, 6n-7 $.

$(6n-7) = (6n-5) +(-2) $

$ - (6n-7) + (6n-5) = 2$

So $2$ is gcd of $6n-5, 6n-7$

Means both are composite. which is a contradiction

Another try : For finite $n$, $6n-1, 6n+1$ is composite. Let $n$ be largest of such number. Both can be written a product of primes. Since prime numbers are infinite , so product can be multiplied by some prime, not in existing list to get a higher number $>n$.

Comment: Both of those numbers are odd.

Comment: Surely you can't get any of these numbers to be divisible by 2 nor 3. How about trying the next two options, 5 and 7? Is there an $n$ such that $6n-1$ is divisible by $5$ and $6n+1$ by $7$? If you find one such $n$, can you easily construct more? The question is much easier than all those convoluted indirect attempts you are trying.

Comment: If $~n = 5k+1~$ then $~6n-1 = 30k + 6-1.$

Comment: @user2661923 i am afraid i didnot understand

Comment: @SophieClad You want to prove that there are an infinite number of composite numbers in the sequence $5, 5+6, 5+12, \cdots $  Consider the subsequence $~5, 5+30, 5+60, 5+90, \cdots.$  Ignoring the first element, every other element of the subsequence is a number larger than $~5~$ which is divisible by $~5~$ and so must be composite.

Comment: Consider $6n-5$ and $6n-7$ when $n$ is a multiple of $35=5\cdot 7$.

Comment: @user2661923 But from the problem statement, the number bigger by $2$ (in the form $6n+1$, with your definition $30k+6+1$) must be composite also.

Comment: (Clarifying an earlier comment.) $2$ is not the gcd of $6n-5$ and $6n-7$ since $2$ isn't a divisor of either number at all.

Comment: Consider $n=35k+1.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó That is a very good point, which the comment of Gerry Myerson remedies.  My previous comments were based on my misreading the original posting.  I misinterpreted the question as requiring that it be shown that the sequence $6n-1$ contains an infinite number of composites, and that the sequence $6n+1$ **separately** contains an infinite number of composites.  It was my mistake for misreading the posting.

Answer (score 2):

We might construct a number $n$ with guaranteed $6n+1$ and $6n-1$ composite:

Choose any 2 primes, $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Select free integer variables $a$, $b$ such that

$$6n-1 = p_1 a$$
$$6n+1 = p_2 b$$

So

$$n = \frac{p_1 a + 1}{6}$$
$$n = \frac{p_2 b - 1}{6}$$

To ensure divisibility by 6, add new constraints on $a$, $b$ such that:

$$p_1a \equiv -1 (mod_6)$$
$$p_2b \equiv 1 (mod_6)$$

Substituting equation 1 into 2:

$$\frac{p_1 a + 1}{6}=\frac{p_2 b - 1}{6}$$
$$a = \frac{p_2b -2}{p_1}$$

To ensure divisibility by $p_1$, add new constraints on $ b$ such that:

$$p_2b \equiv 1 (mod_6),p_2b \equiv 2 (mod_{p_1})$$

---

Eg 1. Let $p_1=5, p_2=7$. Find suitable b satisfying:

$$ 7b \equiv 1 (mod_6)$$
$$ 7b \equiv 2 (mod_5)$$

By numerical search, for instance $b = 31$.

Then $a = \frac{7(31) -2}{5}=43$.

Therefore $n=\frac{7(31) - 1}{6}=36$

Verify:

$$\frac{6n-1}{5}=\frac{6(36)-1}{5} = 43$$
$$\frac{6n+1}{7}=\frac{6(36)+1}{7} = 31$$

---

Eg 2. Let $p_1=101, p_2=149$. Find suitable b satisfying:

$$ 149b \equiv 1 (mod_6)$$
$$ 149b \equiv 2 (mod_{101})$$

By numerical search, for instance $b = 383$.

Then $a = \frac{149(383) -2}{101}=565$.

Therefore $n=\frac{149(383) - 1}{6}=9511$

Verify:

$$\frac{6n-1}{101}=\frac{6(9511)-1}{101} = 565$$
$$\frac{6n+1}{149}=\frac{6(9511)+1}{149} = 383$$